# How to disable/enable a column based on value inserted in other column of a table through Jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I have a table having multiple columns and rows can be added by supplying no. of emp by the user.

Now I want to disable a particular field based on user choice for emp_type field.
For example if user selects **Permanent ** then hours field for that particular row should disable and if user selects **Contract** days field for that row should disable.

**Code**

```
<HTML>
<Body>
<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <head>
 <TABLE id="EMPTable" width="350px" border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Emp_Type</th>
        <th>Hours</th>
        <th>Days</th>
    </tr>
    <TR>
        <td><input type= "text" id = "Id1" name= "Id[]" value="1"  /> </td>
        <td><input type= "text" id="Name1" name= "Name[]" ></td>
        <td><select name="Emp_Type[]" id ="Emp_Type1"onchange="codename()" > 
            <option value="">Emp Type</option>
            <option value="Per">Permanent</option>
            <option value="Con">Contract</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td><input type= "text" id="Hours1" name= "Hours[]" ></td>
        <td><input type= "text" id="Days1"name= "Days[]" ></td> 
    <TR>
    </TABLE>    
     </BR>
    <label>No. of EMP <input type= "text" id="emp_cnt" name= "EMP_Count"></label>
     <button type="button" class='loadtable' > Load table</button>
     <script> 
      $(".loadtable").on('click',function(){
            var num = $("#emp_cnt").val();
            $("#EMPTable tr").slice(2).remove();
            for (var i = 2; i <= num; i++) 
            {
                var data = "<tr><td><input type='text' id='Id"+i+"' name='Id[]' value = "+i+" /><td><input type='text' id='Name"+i+"' name='Name[]' /></td><td><select id='Emp_Type"+i+"' name='Emp_Type[]'><option value='null'>Emp Type</option><option value='Per'>Permanent</option><option value='Con'>Contract</option></td><td><input type='text' id='Hours"+i+"' name='Hours[]'/></td><td><input type='text' id='Days"+i+"' name='Days[]'/></td></tr>";
                $("#EMPTable").append(data);
            }
    });  
</script> 
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Can Someone please guide how to disable a column of a table based on other column selection, where the rows are not fixed for table.

Comment: for example, you have 10 rows (`tr`) in records, and records 2,3,7 should be disabled when event triggered. Here in your HTML, you don't have something to identify such rows quickly. try to give class like `<tr class="permanent" ... />` then you can easily do `$("tr.permanent input").prop("disabled",true);  $("tr.permanent select").prop("disabled",true);`

Comment: @jagad89 , I am not sure what user is going to enter like all can e permanent and all can be on contract. It can only be confirmed once user fills the data..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add a class to the select element and the element you want to enable/disable, for easy selection (class='emp-type' and class='hours' respectively, for example).

Now, attach an event by using jQuery to your table (or tbody) tag:

```
$("#EMPTable").on("change", "tr .emp-type", function(event) { 
    if ($(this).val() == 'Per') {
        $(this).closest("tr").find(".hours").prop("disabled", true);
    } else {
        $(this).closest("tr").find(".hours").prop("disabled", false);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Tistkle, I have done the following changes to get it going for contract also where days should be selected.   `$("#EMPTable").on("change", "tr .emp-type", function(event) { 
   if ($(this).val() == 'Per') {
    $(this).closest("tr").find(".hours").prop("disabled", true);
    $(this).closest("tr").find(".Days").prop("disabled", false);
   } else if ($(this).val() == 'Con'){
    $(this).closest("tr").find(".hours").prop("disabled", false);
    $(this).closest("tr").find(".dys").prop("disabled", True);
   }
})`

Answer (score 0):

i think following code will work , But you have to use unique id's for each `tr` of each `td`

```
        <TABLE id="EMPTable" width="350px" border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Emp_Type</th>
            <th>Hours</th>
            <th>Days</th>
        </tr>
        <TR>
            <td><input type= "text" id = "Id_1" name= "Id[]" value="1"  /> </td>
            <td><input type= "text" id="Name_1" name= "Name[]" ></td>
            <td><select name="Emp_Type[]" id ="Emp_Type_1"onchange="codename()" > 
                <option value="">Emp Type</option>
                <option value="Per">Permanent</option>
                <option value="Con">Contract</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td><input type= "text" id="Hours_1" name= "Hours[]" ></td>
            <td><input type= "text" id="Days_1"name= "Days[]" ></td> 
        <TR>
    </TABLE>

    $(document).on('change','select[id^="Emp_Type_"]', function(){

        var obj = $(this);

        var id = obj.attr('id');

        var indexes = id.split('_');

        var selected_val = obj.val();

        if(selected_val=='Per'){
            obj.closest('tr').find('input#Hours_'+indexes[1]).prop('disabled',true);
            obj.closest('tr').find('input#Days_'+indexes[1]).prop('disabled',false);
        }

        if(selected_val=='Con'){
            obj.closest('tr').find('input#Days_'+indexes[1]).prop('disabled',false);
            obj.closest('tr').find('input#Hours_'+indexes[1]).prop('disabled',true);
        }

    })
```

Comment: use unique id's for each elements e.g. `select` , `td` etc

Comment: Thanks for your help.